# Weighted Gaussian kernel density estimation in `python`

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, kernel-density

**Update**: Weighted samples are now supported by `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623919/weighted-gaussian-kernel-density-estimation-in-python/27623920#27623920) and [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8991) for details.

It is currently not possible to use `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` to estimate the density of a random variable based on [weighted samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Survey_weights). What methods are available to estimate densities of continuous random variables based on weighted samples?

Comment: As of scipy version 1.2, there appears to be a 'weights' option in sp.stats.gaussian_kde which seems to do what you are after now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Neither [`sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity) nor [`statsmodels.nonparametric`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/nonparametric.html) seem to support weighted samples. I modified `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` to allow for heterogeneous sampling weights and thought the results might be useful for others. An example is shown below.

[image: example]

An `ipython` notebook can be found here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/tillahoffmann/f844bce2ec264c1c8cb5

## Implementation details

The weighted arithmetic mean is

[image: weighted arithmetic mean]

The [unbiased data covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_covariance) is then given by
[image: unbiased covariance matrix]

The bandwidth can be chosen by `scott` or `silverman` rules as in `scipy`. However, the number of samples used to calculate the bandwidth is [Kish's approximation for the effective sample size](http://surveyanalysis.org/wiki/Design_Effects_and_Effective_Sample_Size#Kish.27s_approximate_formula_for_computing_effective_sample_size).

Comment: Have you considered asking the `scipy` devs to integrate your code into `scipy` or `statsmodels`?

Comment: Yes, but I have not yet gotten around to implementing resampling and integration. I will issue a pull request once that's done.

Comment: I've been working on a similar problem, but using my own framework rather than modifying scipy.  I hadn't thought to use Kish's approximation.  Do you think it's the best bandwidth estimator?  It reweights every point in the dataset with the same effective sample size. I wonder whether a variable bandwidth might make more sense.

Comment: to resample would it be correct to replace in the resample function randint with np.random.choice(xrange(0, self.n), p=self.weights/np.sum(self.weights), size=size) ?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. However, you may be better of using `np.arange` rather than `xrange` because numpy often converts to arrays internally. But testing would be better than my speculation.

Comment: Very nice code, it works quite well for me. I did find a bug when setting `bw_method` with a scalar: `NameError: name 'string_types' is not defined`

Comment: @xyzzyqed, yes, there is a `from six import string_types` missing.

Comment: Note that as @Ramon noted below, `statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate` supports `weights` (now).

Comment: Now sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity does support weighted samples, as per this [pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10803) and the [manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.fit). If this is true, should this comment be more visible as an edit on the answer?

Comment: Incase anyone check this now, there is an implimentation on `scipy` now. Refer: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html

Answer (score 2):

For univariate distributions you can use `KDEUnivariate` from [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.html#statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate). It is not well documented, but the `fit` methods accepts a `weights` argument. Then you cannot use FFT. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kde import KDEUnivariate

kde1= KDEUnivariate(np.array([10.,10.,10.,5.]))
kde1.fit(bw=0.5)
plt.plot(kde1.support, [kde1.evaluate(xi) for xi in kde1.support],'x-')

kde1= KDEUnivariate(np.array([10.,5.]))
kde1.fit(weights=np.array([3.,1.]), 
         bw=0.5,
         fft=False)
plt.plot(kde1.support, [kde1.evaluate(xi) for xi in kde1.support], 'o-')
```

which produces this figure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the packages PyQT-Fit and statistics for Python. They seem to have kernel density estimation with weighted observations.

Comment: Note that, as of version 1.3.4, PyQT-Fit only supports 1D kernel density estimation.